# How can I find out if Class A directly inherits from Class B in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection

Lets say Class A inherits from Class B which inherits from Class C. Class B directly inherits from Class C but Class A does not directly inherit from class C. I want to use some method like:

```
ClassA.DirectlyInheritsFrom(ClassC) //returns false
ClassB.DirectlyInheritsFrom(ClassC) //returns true
```

Can someone point me to something actually in the C# reflection libraries that accomplishes this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
return childType.BaseType == parentType;
```

(See [`Type.BaseType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) for details.)

That's assuming I've read your question correctly - please let me know if I misunderstood.